# apply custom styles to ngb modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

[please check img for refrence][1]
I am using 3 ngb modals in angular 7 project when i call the function to open the modal dialog it automatically creates the div tags which disturb my custom design and windowClass is also not working here, if I remove these tags in inspect then everything works perfect. what am I missing here?

```
<ng-template  #content1 let-modal>
    <div  class="modal-dialog modal-auto-width" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content model-content-auto-width">
            <div class="modal-body no-spacing">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-xl-5 mx-auto white-bg p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 p-0 mx-auto">
                                <div class="empty-title-bar"></div>
                                <div class="close-batch-btn">
                                    <button *ngIf = "batchCheck" (click)="closeBatch()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    CLOSE BATCH
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
                                <ng-container *ngIf="showRegister">
                                    <div class="row   align-items-center  batch-register-row" *ngFor="let register of showRegister[0].Registers">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4">
                                            <div class=" modal-batch-name" >
                                                <span> {{register.registerName}} </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-person-name" >
                                                <span> John</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-8">
                                            <div class="modal-batch-register-buttons d-flex">
                                                <button *ngIf="register.status == 'o' && register.id != _register " (click)="selectDefaultRegister(register.id); modal.close()" type="button" class="btn " data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <img src="assets/images/open-ico.svg">
                                                Select
                                                </button>
                                                <button *ngIf="register.status == 'o'" (click)="closeRegister(register.id)" type="button" class="btn " data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <img src="assets/images/close-ico.svg">  
                                                Close
                                                </button>
                                                <button (click)="alert('this feature will be available soon')" type="button" class="btn " data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <img src="assets/images/details-ico.svg">  
                                                Details
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ng-container>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

***ts***

```
open(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { backdrop: 'static', windowClass: "model-content-auto-width   modal-auto-width"}).result.then((result) => {
    });
  }
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VzM8OvR

Comment: You're not missing anything. The ng-bootstrap modal indeed wraps everything for you in a modal. That's it's role. All you need to do is to provide the header, body and footer, as shown in the documentation. What's the concrete problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Regarding windowClass not working, what have you tried, and how is it not working? Can you provide a complete minimal example?

Comment: basically when i call the function it creates two divs with own classes those divs disturb the design of the modal, if I remove these divs everything works fine please check the img

Comment: So... remove these divs. Problem solved. Just as the documentation tells you to write a modal.

Comment: used windowClass: "myCustomClass" and it takes the modal to the buttom of the screen

Comment: See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#options. it doesn't do that in the example. So you must be doing something weird. We can't tell what and how to fix the code if you don't post it.

Comment: ngb modal is creating those divs how can I remove?

Comment: You can't. That's how it's designed to work.

Comment: just edited my post, please check

Comment: That's not a complete minimal example where I can reproduce your issue. Post a stackblitz reproducing it. You can start from there for example: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app%2Fmodal-options.ts

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to style the modal elements from the Angular app global style sheet.

*Because of Angular style encapsulation, you cannot style the modal by placing the 'windowClass' on the the style of the component in the modal or on the component opening the modal.*

For example if I want to apply more rounded corners to the modal.

1. Add the style to the global style sheet (src/styles.scss).
   The modal-content class is a style being applied by ngb modal.

```
.modal-rounded {
  .modal-content {
    border-radius: 20px !important;
  }
}
```

2. Pass the global style class to the modal

```
this.modalService.open(content, {centered: true, windowClass: 'modal-rounded'});
```